# Applying laws of propositional logic question: $ \neg \big( p \lor ( \neg p \land q ) \big) \equiv \neg p \land \neg q $

Tags: logic

I need to prove that $ \neg \big( p \lor ( \neg p \land q ) \big) $ is logically equivalent to $ \neg p \land \neg q $ using the laws of propositional logic instead of a truth table. I can't figure out which rules work to transform it to $ \neg p \land \neg q $. I am taking a logic course and I want to practice my logical thinking so that I can be ready on test day. This is one I am practicing with and I tried to do De Morgan's, then associativity then idempotence laws, but I don't think this is correct. I also tried to do absorption and then De Morgan's, but I don't think that works either because of the negations and because I need it to be equivalent to $ \neg p \land \neg q $.

Comment: Please include all the intermediate results so that we can better locate where you ran into trouble, and provide better answers.

Comment: Use in first step distribution and then De Morgan. Add done steps to question if/when you stack and you'll get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using distibution we have:
$$ p \lor ( \neg p \land q ) \equiv \big(p\lor (\neg p)\big)\land \big(p\lor  q\big)  \equiv 1 \land \big(p\lor  q\big) \equiv p\lor  q $$
Then De Morgan gives answer

Answer (score 0):

Using au(bnc)=(aub)n(auc) we can say that
pu(\pnq)= (pu\p)n(puq)= tn(puq)= (puq), t being tautology. Now (puq)= \pn\q by de morgans law.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by  "au(bnc)=(aub)n(auc)" and "pu(\pnq)= (pu\p)n(puq)= tn(puq)= (puq)" and "(puq)= \pn\q"

Comment: @Skytendo I suppose that $u$ means $\vee$ and $n$ means $\wedge$.